# How do I know if I have installed the 64 bit version of R on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, migration

To many of you this will sound totally stupid.

I am completely new to Linux. I installed the 64 bit Ubuntu. And then I installed this software called R which I will use to analyse large datasets.

So I used the sudo apt-get etc etc to install R and it installed fine. But how do I find out if I have installed the 32 bit or 64 bit of R? I need the 64 bit version to take advantage of my 12G of RAM.

In Windows, 64 bit OS can run 32 bit executables. Not sure how Linux works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'file' command to determine the format of an executable (or any other file with a standard header). For example:

```
2 ~$ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
3 ~$ file /lib/libpcre.so.3.12.1
/lib/libpcre.so.3.12.1: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
4 ~$
```

In this case, both the file and the library are 64-bit.

Comment: On Linux, a 64-bit OS can run 32-bit executables if you have the libraries installed. Most often you will.

Further, if you installed R via Ubuntu's packaging system, it is unlikely in the extreme that it wouldn't be the 64-bit version, if you installed the 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: So how do I find where R was install? Again, I am a complete newb.

Comment: I finally found the R executable file. It's located in /usr/lib/R/bin/exec. It reads "R: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped"